# Pandas - scatter plot - rotation of cmap label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scatter-plot

I am doing a simple scatter plot directly via pandas.

My data frame has columns A,B,C.

I plot A vs. B and visualize C values via color.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib as mpl
    
    %matplotlib inline
```

Code:

```
    ycol_label = 'B'
    xcol_label = 'A'
    
    f = df1.plot.scatter(x=xcol_label, y=ycol_label, c='C', cmap='coolwarm')
    
    h = plt.ylabel(ycol_label)
    h.set_rotation(0)
    type(f)
```

How do I change the orientation of that C label which I have on the far right?

I want to rotate it and show it as the B label is shown (on the far left).

I have hard time to even google for this because I don't know how this **rightmost element**
is called (the one with the cool warm color scale). I want to rotate that element's label basically.

[image: pic9]

Comment: No idea why this question was downvoted. It's a valid question, quite tricky even (for non-advanced pandas/matplotlib users).

Comment: I guess the only reason is there is no sample data in the question. Or could also be just some people trolling around. I'll upvote to keep the balance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it using pandas plotting, but with a normal matplotlib plotting it works like this:

```
x = np.random.random(50)
y = np.random.random(50)
c = np.arange(50)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
f = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c, cmap='coolwarm')
cbar = plt.colorbar(f)

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis', rotation=0)
cbar.set_label('z axis', rotation=0)
```

Output:
[image]

---edit---

This is pandas plotting version:

```
x = np.random.random(50)
y = np.random.random(50)
c = np.arange(50)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': x, 'b': y, 'c': c})
ycol_label = 'b'
xcol_label = 'a'

f = df1.plot.scatter(x=xcol_label, y=ycol_label, c='c', cmap='coolwarm')

ff = plt.gcf()
cax = ff.get_axes()[1]
cax.set_ylabel('test', rotation=0)

h = plt.ylabel(ycol_label)
h.set_rotation(0)

type(f)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I found one more solution I think (it is based on your 1st answer; I just had to try a few things in order to get to that colorbar object). Not sure which one is more reliable - your solution or mine. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using pandas and some underlying matplotlib objects.

```
    x_column_label = 'A'
    y_column_label = 'B'
    
    color_column_label = 'C'
    
    ax = df1.plot.scatter(x=x_column_label, y=y_column_label, c=color_column_label, cmap='coolwarm', figsize=(12,6), s=80)
    
    print('================================================================================')
    
    # Here ax is the AxesSubplot object 
    print(ax)
    
    # Get the Figure object from the AxesSubplot object
    f = ax.get_figure()
    
    print(f)
    
    # Get the objects on the axis
    pc = ax.collections
    
    print(pc)
    
    print(len(pc))
    
    # Assumes the colorbar was plotted last 
    color_bar = pc[-1].colorbar
    color_bar.set_label(color_column_label, rotation=0)
    
    h = ax.set_ylabel(y_column_label, rotation=0)
    
    print(color_bar)
    
    print('================================================================================')
```